# Event Log by date

Tags: powershell, logging, get-eventlog

I am trying to capture log files from a specific date and I am not getting any results no matter how many days I go back.

```
Get-EventLog -LogName Application -EntryType Warning -Source MicrosoftDynamicsNAVClientWebClient | Select Message -ExpandProperty Message | Where { ($_.Message -match 'Shutdown') -and ($_.TimeGenerated -gt [datetime]::Today.AddDays('-1')) }
```

Here is the list of log files

```
Message                                                     TimeGenerated                                              
-------                                                     -------------                                              
Shutdown has occurred ...                                   1/18/2017 12:01:52 AM                                      
Shutdown has occurred ...                                   1/18/2017 12:01:52 AM                                      
Shutdown has occurred ...                                   1/18/2017 12:01:52 AM                                      
Shutdown has occurred ...                                   1/16/2017 7:01:53 PM                                       
Shutdown has occurred ...                                   1/16/2017 7:01:53 PM                                       
Shutdown has occurred ...                                   1/16/2017 7:01:53 PM                                       
Shutdown has occurred ...                                   1/15/2017 2:01:39 PM                                       
Shutdown has occurred ...                                   1/15/2017 2:01:39 PM                                       
Shutdown has occurred ...                                   1/15/2017 2:01:39 PM                                       
Shutdown has occurred ...                                   1/14/2017 1:58:47 PM                                       
Shutdown has occurred ...                                   1/14/2017 1:58:47 PM                                       
Shutdown has occurred ...                                   1/14/2017 1:58:47 PM                                       
Shutdown has occurred ...                                   1/13/2017 8:58:46 AM                                       
Shutdown has occurred ...                                   1/13/2017 8:58:46 AM                                       
Shutdown has occurred ...                                   1/13/2017 8:58:46 AM                                       
Shutdown has occurred ...                                   1/12/2017 3:58:45 AM                                       
Shutdown has occurred ...                                   1/12/2017 3:58:45 AM
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that you use the the `Select` cmdlet to expand `Message`. So then when you try to filter on `TimeGenerated` that property isn't there. If you only want the messages, then select after you filter.

```
Get-EventLog -LogName Application -EntryType Warning -Source MicrosoftDynamicsNAVClientWebClient | Where { ($_.Message -match 'Shutdown') -and ($_.TimeGenerated -gt [datetime]::Today.AddDays(-1)) } | Select -ExpandProperty Message
```

Comment: I am forever getting bit by that formatting bug. I make this mistake over and over. I guess its my sense of order that screws me up I like to see things correctly up front rather than get everything and format it afterwards. Thank you for knocking some sense into me Ben. Very good and concise answer.